# Can we create a view which refers to a view which is not exist at that point of time?

Tags: sql-server-2008, view, roundhouse

We have a view definition which internally uses other 5 views. When we use a RoundhousE to execute the database scripts, these view scripts are getting executed in alphabetical order. Hence out of these 5 views, which are used inside the main view, only 3 views are getting executed ahead of the main view and rest 2 views are not yet created and hence the main view script throws error. How can we solve this apart from renaming the views?

Comment: Why not just create all the views ahead of time? They don't use up hardly any space (unless you index them and thus materialize them). You need to post the code here and explain the purpose. You have asked an [XY Quesiton](http://xyproblem.info/)

Comment: @scsimon The OP explained they are using RH to create and update the views, so I don't see it as an XY question (based on the reference).

Comment: Based on your suggested answer you solidify my point @ferventcoder

Comment: @scsimon So broader picture - RH (RoundhousE) is a database migration engine. Your first suggestion about creating all views ahead of time suggests you don't understand what RH is or does (I could be incorrect here). RH would create and manage the views during the database migration. Anyone familiar with RH would not see this as an XY question. HTH

Answer (score 2):

Either in the [wiki](https://github.com/chucknorris/roundhouse/wiki), or in the [source docs](https://github.com/chucknorris/roundhouse/tree/master/docs), I believe we cover this exact scenario. If not, we should add it there.

The solution when you have a dependency on order is to rename the files (not the views). Typically you would put the file names in order based on "0000_" (e.g. `0001_viewname.sql`, `0002_viewname.sql`, etc) at the front of the view name, but you could also just move the name of the main view to "z_" to place it after the other views.

I know you asked how you can solve this apart from renaming the view files, but renaming the files ***is*** how you resolve this issue.

Comment: Thanks!! Yeah, that is one option. But we are not sure whether RH follows any particular order while picking the files. So we kept CREATE statement of all the views in a single file.

Comment: It's alphabetical order, but that option works as well.